# static variable's address can access by other files or not

Tags: c, pointers, static

I have one question about the static variable in C language.
For example, there are two files, one is "Action.c" and another is "Result.c"

**[In Action.c File]**
`

```
static uint8_t actionResult[10] = {0x00};
void getActionResult (uint8_t** resultPtr)
{
    *resultPtr = actionResult;
}
```

**[In Result.c]**

```
void main (void)
{
    uint8_t* getResultPtr = NULL;
    getActionResult(&getResultPtr);
}
```

I want to know this is legal method to get value from "Action.c" file or not. And also want to know transfer static variable address to other file is bad idea or not?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, it is legal.   A static variable is visible only within the compilation unit (aka source file) where it is defined.  But if a function provides its address, that is fine, since the static variable exists until program termination.      Such a thing isn't necessarily a good idea, but it is one option, albeit there are alternatives.    And, by the way, `main()` returns `int` in standard C, not `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it legal? Yes. A file-level static variable cannot be seen from outside a translation unit but, if that translation unit publishes the address somehow (as you have), it can be accessed or changed by dereferencing that address.

Is it a good idea? Not really. The whole *point* of file-level statics is to protect them from things outside the translation unit. If you're going to allow this, there's really no point in marking it static at all.

Just define it as `uint8_t actionResult[10] = {0x00};` and have `main` use the variable name rather than getting and dereferencing its address.